# Money counter with Javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a money counter with javascript using (/\d(?=(\d{3})+.)/g, "$&,"); to format the money.
This pulls through fine, but I want to add animation on every pound. The number will not always start on 00.

So I have pulled through the code and have a "span" with the full amount eg £1,520,66.When the pound column goes up so £1,521.00 I want to add animation. But I have no idea how to target that specific number.
the const below has the full number. So how canb i target the pound column?

const counterAmount =`£` + jackpot.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+.)/g, "$&,");

Comment: How are you animating the text? Please format your code and read the section on [mcve]

Comment: I don't have much more text at the moment.
Basically I have the above variable 
const counterAmount =£ + jackpot.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+.)/g, "$&,");

so its again of htmlID.innerHTML=counterAmount.

This gives me the value i'm looking for. But lets say counterAmount is 1,234,88.
I want to animate this when it gets to 1,235.00. 

As i've never really done regex before
const counterAmount =£ + jackpot.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+.)/g, "$&,");
Can io target certain numbers from the var?

Comment: Delete your comment and post the relevant info in your question. Use the bracket button `[<>]`, or wrap code in ``` , or indent with 4 spaces, or use the other bracket button `[{}]`. And I'll ask one more time: ***How are you animating text?***